# What Perl 6 modules can read/write XLSX files?

Tags: xlsx, xlsxwriter, raku

Am trying to read and update some MS Excel (xlsx) files with Perl 6. What are the modules that I should be downloading?

I do see a Perl 6 writer by googling:

https://github.com/evanmiller/XLSX-Writer

Is this the one to use for writing?

I don't see any module that is Perl 6 specific for reading in XLSX. Is there some module for reading too?

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is **no**; there aren't currently any XLSX ***reading*** modules in Perl 6 (at least not that I know of).

However, ***do you really need to be using an XLSX format?*** If you could switch to using tab-delimited or csv-formatted files, I'd recommend that. I'm surprised by how often complicated formats are used for very simple data.

But **if** you must use XLSX, then I'd recommend using Perl 5 with one of its well known and well tested modules.

But **if** you must use Perl 6, then here's what little I know:

1. For writing files, the [`XLSX::Writer` Perl 6 module](https://github.com/evanmiller/XLSX-Writer) that you mention is "a wrapper for the libxlsxwriter C library", which just writes XLSX files, but [cannot read them](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/introduction.html).
2. For reading files

   a. You might try using XLSX Perl 5 modules via `Inline::Perl5`.

   b. You could try creating a Perl 6 wrapper for a C or C++ library such as [XLSX I/O](https://brechtsanders.github.io/xlsxio/) or [xlnt](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt).

If you come across or create a Perl 6 module that reads XLSX files, please post that information as an answer to your own question and notify me via a comment.

Comment: For CSV formatted files, there's `Text::CSV` in a native Perl 6 version.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms see below.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "XLSX" on https://modules.raku.org/ with the query https://modules.raku.org/search/?q=XLSX you will discover the following two modules:

**Spreadsheet::XLSX** Work with Excel (XLSX) spreadsheets.
https://github.com/jnthn/spreadsheet-xlsx

`AND`

**Spreadsheet::Libxlsxio** An interface to libxlsxio, a C library to read and write XLSX files
https://modules.raku.org/dist/Spreadsheet::Libxlsxio:cpan:FRITH
https://github.com/frithnanth/raku-Spreadsheet-Libxlsxio

`NOTE:`

These two modules can also be found on https://raku.land/ via the query https://raku.land/?q=XLSX